# Convert String date into java.util.Date in the dd/MM/yyyy format

Tags: java, date

I read more questions on the web but I dont' find a solution yet.

I have a **String** like "14/05/1994", exactly in this format.

I need to covert it into **java.util.Date** in the **same format**.

I tried:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dataFrom = new Date();
    dataFrom = df.format("14/05/1994");
```

But the result is: Sat May 14 00:00:00 CET 1994

It's possibile have as a result: 14/05/1994 not as a String, but as java.util.Date?

Comment: `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");` `Date date = df.parse("14/05/1994");` `String d = df.format(date);`

Comment: @DavideFruci Please search StackOverflow before posting. This topic has been addressed in many hundreds, if not thousands, of Questions and Answers. In brief: Do not conflate a String object with a date-time object. Date-time objects *parse* strings and *generate* strings in various formats. Date-time objects themselves do not have a "format".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` doesn't *have* a format.  It's just a date.

When you print it out, e.g. using `toString()`, it uses a default format, which is what you're seeing.  But you *have* that date.

```
Date dataFrom = new Date();
dataFrom = df.format("14/05/1994");
```

I don't think that can be your code because `DateFormat.format` accepts a `Date` and returns a `String`, not the other way around.  You might mean `df.parse`, which would get you the results you describe.  But if you take your `SimpleDateFormat` and use its `format` method on the `Date`, then you should get back out `14/05/1994` as you want.  A `java.util.Date` doesn't *have* a format, though.